# regarding indexes. i tried a lot but didn't really understand it. how does the realtion really look like? here is it

Tags: database, indexing

Consider a table storing temperature readings taken by sensors:

Temps(sensorID, time, temp)
Assume the pair of attributes [sensorID,time] is a key. Consider the following query:
   select * from Temps
   where sensorID = 'sensor541'
   and time = '05:11:02'

Consider the following scenarios:

A - No index is present on any attribute of Temps

B - An index is present on attribute sensorID only

C - An index is present on attribute time only

D - Separate indexes are present on attributes sensorID and time

E - A multi-attribute index is present on (sensorID,time)

Suppose table Temps has 50 unique sensorIDs and each sensorID has exactly 20 readings. Furthermore there are exactly 10 readings for every unique time in Temps.

For each scenario A-E, determine the maximum number of tuples that might be accessed to answer the query, assuming one "best" index is used whenever possible. (Don't count the number of index accesses.) Which of the following combinations of values is correct?

1) A:1000, C:1000, D:10
 2) B:10, C:10, E:10
 3) B:20, C:10, E:1
 4) B:1000, C:10, D:10

Comment: One problem here is your statement that 'there are exactly 10 readings for every unique time in Temps'. Is that 10 per sensor per time, or are there only readings for 10 sensors (out of 50) for any one time? Once you work that out, then consider that on most RDBMSs, the data (temp) is stored in the same place as the Primary Key so finding the PK also finds the data. Apart from that, Homework, blech!

Comment: thanks simon!  but that's the same thing i am confused in. that's the exact question statement. the answer is option 3. i am still unable to understand. maybe you can get something out of it

Comment: Not possible until you answer my question about the number of temps. Also, none of the answers match the question in that the question says 'For each scenario' and each answer only includes 3 out of the 5. If the question is actually answerable, you need to post it exactly as it seems you haven't described it explicitly enough (a hint you don't actually understand the question - the scenario or what you're being asked about it). And as it's homework, a hint is all I'll be giving anyway :(

Comment: thanks a lot simon.. i got it... i wasn't paying attention to the key [sensorID,time]. there are 20 unique values of time per sensor and each unique time has exactly 10 temperature values. so i guess the complete answer would be A:1000 B:20 C:10 D:10 E:1. correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 1):

Scenario A: Since there are no indexes, all tuples of the table may need to be accessed to look for 'sensor541' and '05:11:02'. The number of tuples in Temps is 50 (unique sensorIDs) * 20 (number of readings per sensor) = 1000.

Scenario B: Using the index on sensorID, 20 readings will match the given sensorID, and all 20 tuples may need to be accessed to look for a matching time.

Scenario C: Using the index on time, 10 readings will match the given time, and all 10 tuples may need to be accessed to look for a matching sensorID.

Scenario D: Using the time index is better than using the sensorID index, so the time index is used and is the same as scenario C (10 tuples).

Scenario E: The index on [sensorID, time] will directly find the single matching tuple, if there is one.